# Docker for Linux is failing

Tags: docker

I am new learner for Docker. I have a very simple question.
I want my application to work on Linux system but I am writing application in Windows. So do I need to install Docker for Windows or Linux?

If I run using Docker for Linux, I am not getting option to run in windows and it is getting failed (I understand it might be some other unrelated error) but I need to confirm if my approach is correct or not.

Am I right in installing Docker for Linux?
Also, in case I plan to move to AWS, what docker I need in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider docker as any software. if your OS is windows you install windows version of a software. if your is a linux distro then you install linux version of a software.

So you need to install docker for windows afterwards you can install any docker image/container you want under your operating system. Could be windows, linux or anything else.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I could not get this info anywhere in such simple words.